# Numpy linalg on multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Is there a way to use `numpy.linalg.det` or `numpy.linalg.inv` on an `nx3x3` array (a line in a multiband image), for example? Right now I am doing something like:

```
det = numpy.array([numpy.linalg.det(i) for i in X])
```

but surely there is a more efficient way. Of course, I could use `map`:

```
det = numpy.array(map(numpy.linalg.det, X))
```

Any other more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no substantially more efficient way than what you have.  You can save some memory by first creating an empty array for the results and writing all results directly to that array:

```
res = numpy.empty_like(X) 
for i, A in enumerate(X):
    res[i] = numpy.linalg.inv(A)
```

This won't be any faster, though -- it will only use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

a "normal" determinant is only defined for a matrix (dimension=2), so if that's what you want i don't see another way.

if you really want to compute the determinant of a cube then you could try to implement one of the ways described here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdeterminant

notice that it is not necessarily the same value as the one you're currently computing.

Comment: There are lines of length n in an 9 band image (represented by a 3x3 matrix). There are n 2d matrices.

Comment: then, as i said, i don't think there's much to improve on your current method. see Sven's answer he suggested a more memory efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

New answer to an old question: Since version 1.8.0, numpy supports evaluating a batch of 2D matrices. For a batch of MxM matrices, the input and output now looks like:

> linalg.det(a)
> Compute the determinant of an array.
>
> Parameters a(…, M, M) array_like
> Input array to compute determinants for.
>
> Returns det(…) array_like
> Determinant of a.

Note the ellipsis. There can be multiple "batch dimensions", where for example you can evaluate a determinants on a meshgrid.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html